# How do I change the choices in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-south

I have a Django model that uses the `choices` [attribute](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices).

```
COLOR_CHOICES = (
    ('R', 'Red'),
    ('B', 'Blue'),
)
class Toy(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
```

My code is in production and now I'd like to add additional choices.

```
COLOR_CHOICES = (
        ('R', 'Red'),
        ('B', 'Blue'),
        ('G', 'Green'),
 )
```

How do I go about doing this? Does Django use Database constraints to enforce choices? Do I need to do a Database migration (I'm using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/))? Or does Django just enforce the choices restriction in Python code and all I have to do is change the code and restart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django doesn't enforce choices on a database level, it only uses them for the presentation of the widgets and in validation. If you want them a bit more 'dynamic', for example to have different ones on different servers you could define them via `settings.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

COLOR_CHOICES = getattr(settings, 'COLOR_CHOICES',(
        ('R', 'Red'),
        ('B', 'Blue'),
        ('G', 'Green'),
 ))
```

Then you could define different choices in your `settings.py` (no need for any database migration!).

Comment: That's a cool idea. But you're saying that as it is there's no need for DB migration. I just need to change the code and restart?

Comment: yes... and besides that shouldnt be the big deal to try it, right?

Comment: Bit late to the party here...  What if I want to change all the 'Reds' to 'Greens'?

Comment: @Ferguzz `MyModel.objects.filter(color="R").update(color="G")`

Answer (score 2):

The field is `models.CharField` so the database will treat it like any other `models.CharField` set up in django :)

No, it doesn't enforce choices / you don't need to touch your DB.